# Convert ch to Px in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Notes:** I tried all questions & answers related to this topic.

My Question very simple and clear `1ch = how many px?`

My sample [`code`](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/4e02r9ub/2/)

**Relatest search article**

1. [Understanding-css-units](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/understanding-css-units/)
2. [css Units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)
3. [css-unit-conversion-calculator](https://sabe.io/tools/css-unit-conversion-calculator)

Comment: what do you want to know?  `1ch = how many px?` or you wanted to solve your issue?

Comment: Ch is a function of font-width so there is no set conversion calculation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no constant `ch` to `px` conversion because, like `rem` and `em`, `ch` is a relative unit. `1ch` is equal to the width of the [`0` glyph (ZERO, U+0030)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Values_and_Units#:%7E:text=%220%22%20(ZERO%2C%20U%2B0030)%20glyph) of the current font.

So if the `0` glyph is 8px wide, then `1ch = 8px` (in the example below, this happens to be equal to 0.5em, but this is not a guarantee).

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.font-20 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.em { 
  background: red;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}

.rem { 
  background: blue;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
}

.ch { 
  background: green;
  height: 2ch;
  width: 2ch;
}

.px {
  background: orange;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>font-size: 16px (root size)</h1>
  <div class="ch" title="2ch"></div>  
  <div class="em" title="1em"></div>
  <div class="rem" title="1rem"></div>
  <div class="px" title="16px"></div> 
</div>
<div class="font-20">
  <h1>font-size: 20px</h1>
  <div class="ch" title="2ch"></div>  
  <div class="em" title="1em"></div>
  <div class="rem" title="1rem"></div>
  <div class="px" title="16px"></div>
</div>
```